# $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{r-2}{(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was solving this question

$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{r-2}{(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)}$

My approach,

$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{3(r+2)-2(r+4)}{(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)}$

$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{(r+3)(r+4)}$ - $\frac{2}{(r+2)(r+3)}$

This is of the form, $V(r+1) - V(r)$

$= \frac{3}{(n+3)(n+4)}$ - $\frac{2}{(1+2)(1+3)} \\ (n \to \infty)$

$= \frac{-1}{6}$

But the answer is $ \frac{1}{12}$

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\color{red}3}{(r+3)(r+4)}-\frac{\color{blue}2}{(r+2)(r+3)}\right)\tag1$$is *not* of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigl(V(n+1)-V(n)\bigr)$, since the numerators in $(1)$ are distinct.

Comment: In the solution given in the book, the have used $V(r)-V(r+1)$ form on $\sum \frac{r}{(r+2)(r+3)}-\frac{r+1}{(r+3)(r+4)}$ ,isn't the numerator here too different?

Comment: If $V(r)=\frac r{(r+2)(r+3)}$, then $V(r+1)=\frac{r+1}{(r+3)(r+4)}$. But if $V(r)=\frac2{(r+2)(r+3)}$, then $V(r+1)=\frac2{(r+3)(r+4)}\ne\frac3{(r+3)(r+4)}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=1}^N \frac{r-2}{(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)} 
= & \sum_{r=1}^N\left[\frac{3}{(r+3)(r+4)}-\frac{2}{(r+2)(r+3)}\right] \\
= & 3 \sum_{r=1}^N\left[\frac{1}{(r+3)(r+4)}-\frac{1}{(r+2)(r+3)}\right]+\sum_{r=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{r+2}-\frac{1}{r+3}\right) \\
= & 3\left[\frac{1}{(N+3)(N+4)}-\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}\right]+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{N+3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $N\rightarrow \infty$ gives the infinite series
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{r-2}{(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)}=3\left(-\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}\right)+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{12}
$$